# javascript typeof index in the iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const digits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
for (const index in digits) {
  console.log(typeof digits[index]);
  console.log(digits[index]);
}


console.log('========================')

const digitsz = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
for (const indexz in digitsz) {
  console.log(typeof indexz);
  console.log(indexz);
}
```

ok now the return of the first typeof is number while the second one is string 
i dont know why is that ?? while in the array its already numbers in there

Comment: Try with an array of booleans or of objects. That should show that only the first `typeof` tests the values in the array.

Comment: The use of two separate arrays here is a complete red herring. The difference is what you are checking the type of and nothing to do with the differences between the arrays.

Comment: In Javascript, everything is an object. Even Arrays.

In the second loop, you are logging `indexz` which is a key in the array object and thus it is of type `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'A for...in loop only iterates over enumerable, non-Symbol properties. Objects created from built–in constructors like Array and Object have inherited non–enumerable properties from Object.prototype and String.prototype, such as String's indexOf() method or Object's toString() method. The loop will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype (properties closer to the object in the prototype chain override prototypes' properties).'
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: thank you so much That's explaned alot sorry for borying questions